# Enforcing User Answer Order on HTML Form Quiz

Tags: html

I am looking for a way to force an answer order on an HTML form quiz.  This is relatively straightforward, I think--I just want the user to be forced to answer the questions in order.

Here is a coded example:

```
<form method="post">

Answer the Questions!

<P id="question1" onclick="showQuestion('question2')" >1. The word which means "house" is:<BR>
<input type="radio" required="required" name="1.The word which means house is" value="maison">maison<BR>
<input type="radio" name="1.The word which means house is" value="quatre">quatre<BR>
<input type="radio" name="1.The word which means house is" value="soleil">soleil<BR>
<input type="radio" name="1.The word which means house is" value="poisson">poisson<BR>
</p>

<P id="question2" style="display:none;" onclick="showQuestion('question3')" >2. The word which means "fish" is:<BR>
<input type="radio" required="required" name="2. The word which means fish is" value="maison">maison<BR>
<input type="radio" name="2. The word which means fish is" value="valise">valise<BR>
<input type="radio" name="2. The word which means fish is" value="soleil">soleil<BR>
<input type="radio" name="2. The word which means fish is" value="poisson">poisson<BR>
</p>

<P id="question3" style="display:none;">3. The word which means "suitcase" is:<BR>
<input type="radio" name="3. The word which means suitcase is" value="renard">renard<BR>
<input type="radio" name="3. The word which means suitcase is" value="valise">valise<BR>
<input type="radio" name="3. The word which means suitcase is" value="soleil">soleil<BR>
<input type="radio" name="3. The word which means suitcase is" value="poisson">poisson<BR>
</p> 

</form>
```

Here is a function that will display the next question after one is answered, but what I really want to do is display all 3 questions and have the required validator fail if the user answer questions out of order.

```
<script>
window.showQuestion = function (val){
   var x = document.getElementById(val);
   x.style.display = 'inline';
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you will need a bit javascript

Comment: HTML alone cannot do this, you will need to use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for conditional Form fields with css my advice is to take a look at this **[PEN.](https://codepen.io/jaydevs/pen/OmPmWe)**

or you can define in JS like this.

```
var selected = $("#question1 option:selected").val();
```

and change options like this.

```
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
```